# How to go to a list of 500 websites sequentially with a single button

Tags: google-chrome

I have a text file with a list of websites that goes something like this:

```
http://sb9.astro.ulb.ac.be/ProcessMainform.cgi?Catalog=HD&Id=58872++&Coord=&Epoch=2000&radius=10&unit=arc+min    
http://sb9.astro.ulb.ac.be/ProcessMainform.cgi?Catalog=HD&Id=58515++&Coord=&Epoch=2000&radius=10&unit=arc+min    
...
```

What I need to do is go to each website one by one, perhaps by just hitting enter and having it open in a new tab. I don't know if I'd build a script for this, or if there is already a tool available to do something like this.

I have some experience in Java, Python, and Fortran, but I am by no means a professional programmer.

I appreciate any help you may be able to provide.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to test these website for traffic or actually view them physically? If you just need to test them then python is easy enough for that. Requires curl installed on the system path.

```
file_in = open("input_list.txt", "r")
file_lines = file_in.readlines()

file_in.close()

for x in range(0, len(file_lines)): # strip the trailing \n character
    file_lines[x] = file_lines[x].strip()

for url in file_lines:
    os.system("curl " + url)
```